# Trying to use 2 lists in a for loop not working

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm trying to do some basic python with DNA sequences but now I'm running into a little problem.

This is my initial code:

```
def positie(enzyme):
    pos = sequentie.find(enzyme.lower())
    print (pos)

def searchopdracht(enzyme):
    if enzyme.lower() in sequentie:
        print(enzyme, " does cut, at location:")
        positie(enzyme)
        print(" ")
    else:
        print(enzyme, "does not cut")
        print(" ")

for enzyme in [DdeI, BspMII, EcoRI, HindIII, TaqI]:
    searchopdracht(enzyme)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
CTGAG does cut, at location: 1022
TCCGGA does not cut  
GAATTC  does cut, at location: 1449
AAGCTT  does cut, at location: 77
TCGA  does cut, at location: 171
```

All fine and working, but I want the names of the enzymes to be displayed instead of the sequences,  for example, not "CTGAG does cut, at location: 1022" but "DdeI does cut, at location: 1022"

This is what I tried (but gives no output whatsoever), but feel free to give other suggestions:

```
def positie( enzyme ):
    pos = sequentie.find(enzyme.lower())
    print (pos)

def searchopdracht(enzyme, enzyme_name):
    if enzyme.lower() in sequentie:
        print(enzyme_name," does cut, at location:")
        positie(enzyme)
        print(" ")
    else:
        print(enzyme_name, "does not cut")
        print(" ")

list1 = [DdeI, BspMII, EcoRI, HindIII, TaqI]
list2 = ["DdeI", "BspMII", "EcoRI", "HindIII", "TaqI"]

for (enzyme, enzyme_name) in (list1, list2):
    searchopdracht(enzyme)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `enzyme_name` as an argument to `searchopdracht()`, and use `zip` to create tuple pairs of your input:

```
for enzyme, enzyme_name in zip(list1, list2):
    searchopdracht(enzyme, enzyme_name) # added argument
```